# How to configure AppEngine Gradle plugin using Kotlin DSL

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

As documented on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference the AppEngine Gradle plugin offers configuration like:

```
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
  run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
    port = 8080                 // default
  }

  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
  }
}
```

How should such a configuration look like when using a `build.gradlke.kts`?

I was looking at to see the AppEngine tasks but don't understand to connect this to a proper Kotlin DSL setup.

**EDIT**

When simply adding the above block to the `build.gradle.kts` IntelliJ complains with:

- Unresolved reference: port
- Unresolved reference: deploy

and when running Gradle from cml I get:

> Could not open cache directory azhqxsd1d4xoovq4o5dzec6iw (/Users/test/.gradle/caches/4.5/gradle-kotlin-dsl/azhqxsd1d4xoovq4o5dzec6iw).
>   Internal error: unable to compile script, see log for details

**EDIT2**

Added `plugins` and `buildscript` blocks below:

```
val kotlinVersion                    = property("kotlin.version")
val javaVersion                      = "1.8"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        maven("https://repo.spring.io/milestone")
        maven("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.4")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

apply {
    plugin("com.google.cloud.tools.appengine")
    plugin("org.springframework.boot")
}

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.2.0"
    `war`
    `idea`
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl") version "1.0.9"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.3.RELEASE"
}
```

**EDIT3**

I see this being generated by `kotlinDslAccessorsReport`:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the [appengine][com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension] project extension.
 */
val Project.`appengine`: com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension get() =
    extensions.getByName("appengine") as com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension

/**
 * Configures the [appengine][com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension] project extension.
 */
fun Project.`appengine`(configure: com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension.() -> Unit): Unit =
    extensions.configure("appengine", configure)
```

But honestly I have no idea how this could help me further.

Comment: More often than not, configuration can be copied from groovy to kotlin-dsl with minimal corrections accomodating kotlin syntax. I'd say the provided snippet should look the same in kotlin-dsl.

 If you tried it and it does not work, please provide your build.gradle.kts file and the error message you're getting when trying to build it.

Comment: @Czar I edited the post providing the error messages I see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add your `plugins` or `buildscript` block for how you apply the plugin to the build?

Comment: Marcel, the error message you're getting says that script is invalid for some reason, we need to find it, the best would be to provide full script, if you can't, we'll need at least what @mkobit specified.

Comment: Added the plugins and buildscript block. Note when I remove the `appengine` I get no error anymore.

Comment: PS: here is gist file containing full build script; https://gist.github.com/marceloverdijk/2c74363ca5bac7f61ece184ca9d25a02 (I only had to remove 2 custom tasks)

Comment: Groovy build scripts work because of dynamic resolution. The  `appengine` can be an extra property, project property, task name, extension name, conventions, and some other objects. With Kotlin build scripts, everything is statically typed. The `kotlin-dsl` project generates some of those static accessors for plugins that are applied with the `plugins {}` block. You can run `./gradlew kotlinDslAccessorsReport` to see what is generated and maybe those will help you figure out what is being generated. Also, if it is a task, you print you information like `tasks.getByName["appengine"]`

Comment: @mkobit I added the output of `kotlinDslAccessorsReport` but I'm afraid it doesn't help me much. The AppEngine plugin provides many tasks like `appengineRun`, `appengineDeploy` etc. Which tasks are available is also dependent on the setup of the project, e.g. existence of certain file. So I guess the plugin does a lot of dynamic configuration..

Comment: @mkobit note then when I add the AppEngine plugin to the `plugins {}` block I get the following error: `Plugin [id: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine', version: '1.3.4'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine:com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.gradle.plugin:1.3.4')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to have `kotlin-dsl` generate static accessors before compile time for applied plugins you must use the `plugins {}` block and not the `buildscript {}` block. `buildscript {}` will still make the dependencies visible to the script classpath, but you will not get those.

As you noticed, the plugin's Maven coordinates that may be different than the plugin Id. You can handle this in the `settings.gradle` with the [`pluginManagement`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.management.PluginManagementSpec.html) specification (an example for Android plugin is [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/a5de7d1b485ae30755d4ac09e54063cd9e9678e3/samples/hello-android/settings.gradle.kts#L8-L11). Here is how I handle that (and using `war` plugin for minimal application):

`build.gradle,kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("com.google.cloud.tools.appengine") version "1.3.4"
  `war`
}
```

`settings.gradle`

```groovy
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
  }
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
      if (requested.id.id == "com.google.cloud.tools.appengine") {
        useModule("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I have the plugin applied and `kotlin-dsl` will generate the accessors before script compilation.

Running `./gradlew kotlinDslAccessorsReport` and perusing through it I see this in the output:

```kotlin
/**
 * Retrieves the [appengine][com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension] project extension.
 */
val Project.`appengine`: com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension get() =
  extensions.getByName("appengine") as com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension

/**
 * Configures the [appengine][com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension] project extension.
 */
fun Project.`appengine`(configure: com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension.() -> Unit): Unit =
    extensions.configure("appengine", configure)
```

Now, you can see that the `appengine { ... }` code block will work correctly in the top level. We just need to figure out what can go inside of it based on its type. Note that if we were using `buildscript {}` instead of `plugins {}`, you would have to either copy/paste these accessors yourself or do something like `extensions.getByType(com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension::class)` in your build script.

Doing some searching you can find the source code for `AppEngineExtension` [on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/core/AppEngineExtension.java). Unfortunately, it does not have any methods or fields on it. It is basically used as an "extension holder" class, in that other extensions are added to it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/619670d51082ba76ae128918f7f4ffd51fb21a58/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/core/AppEngineCorePlugin.java#L73-L92) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/4d3634e9ddc7a68ad6aae8d30d4fcf1779279a14/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/standard/AppEngineStandardPlugin.java#L74-L78) (and probably other places). This means that we need to do some class cast tricks to be able to configure this object. The source code is IMO the only way to really figure out how to access these kinds of objects.

Below shows how we can configure the `deploy` extension, which is a [`DeployExtension`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/619670d51082ba76ae128918f7f4ffd51fb21a58/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/core/DeployExtension.java) and how we can configure the `run` extension, which is a [`RunExtension`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/4ca7537d7d156a569209d501f111783f893a9530/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/standard/RunExtension.java).

```kotlin
import com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.DeployExtension
import com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.standard.RunExtension

appengine {
  ((this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.getByName("run") as RunExtension).apply {
    port = 8080
  }
  ((this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.getByName("deploy") as DeployExtension).apply {
    stopPreviousVersion = true // default - stop the current version
    promote = true
  }
}
```

There are a few different ways to accomplish the above, but that is the approach I took. The plugin itself should offer friendlier methods for configuration until [kotlin-dsl/457](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/457) is resolved, so I opened [an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/issues/191#issuecomment-361391560)

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer and raising the issue! Hope this can be done easier in the future as this unfortunately will scare users away from using Kotlin buildscript.

Comment: Btw the `pluginManagement` part is that needed because the AppEngine plugin is not published in the Gradle Plugin Repositories?

Comment: There are 2 parts to it: `repositories` used for the right place to locate the plugin (because I don't believe it is published to the plugin portal), and the `resolutionStrategy` is used because a marker artifact isn't published for Gradle's plugin resolution process (can see some more info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:using_the_java_gradle_plugin_development_plugin)) so it allows you to explicitly say which module the plugin Id comes from.

Comment: Is this something the Google AppEngine plugin can improve on? E.g. publishing to plugin portal and/or create a marker artifact? I mean if users could skip the settings.gradle part that would be a win already I think.

Comment: Yes, I think both aspects can be improved. The marker artifact and `java-library` plugin will make the need for `pluginManagement.resolutionStrategy.eachPlugin`. The plugin still may be published to Google's Maven repository or JCenter or somewhere else like `jcenter`, so you may still need the `pluginManagement.repositories` part. The plugin could add some methods to those extensions to make it easier for Kotlin consumption until [kotlin-dsl/457](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/457) is resolved.

Comment: As of today [kotlin-dsl/457](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/457) has been resolved. Any updates for the answer @mkobit if possible?

Answer (score 4):

Type-safe approach using version 2.0 of the appengine gradle plugin:

```
import com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.standard.AppEngineStandardExtension

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.0.0-rc5")
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    war
    kotlin("jvm") version "..."
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
apply {
    plugin("com.google.cloud.tools.appengine")
}

configure<AppEngineStandardExtension> {
    deploy {
        projectId = "..."
        version = "..."
        stopPreviousVersion = true // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use `AppEngineAppYamlExtension` instead:

configure<AppEngineAppYamlExtension> {
    deploy {
        projectId = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
  version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
    }
}

Comment: Do you know if there's any update? Why couldn't this just be under the regular `plugins` block with an `id` prefix?

Comment: good question... no idea how to make this work with multiplatform plugin either... hashtag gradle plugs don't play nice together in kts.